# blstm() : Missing required positional arguments

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm using Python 3.7. I got the following error after using this code

```
def blstm(inp_dim,vocab_size, embed_size, num_classes, learn_rate):   
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size, input_length=inp_dim, trainable=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(embed_size)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.50))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model


 

def get_model(m_type,inp_dim, vocab_size, embed_size, num_classes, learn_rate):
    if m_type == 'cnn':
        model = cnn(inp_dim, vocab_size, embed_size, num_classes, learn_rate)
    elif m_type == 'lstm':
        model = lstm_keras(inp_dim, vocab_size, embed_size, num_classes, learn_rate)
    elif m_type == "blstm":
        model = blstm(inp_dim)
    elif m_type == "blstm_attention":
        model = blstm_atten(inp_dim, vocab_size, embed_size, num_classes, learn_rate)
    else:
        print ("ERROR: Please specify a correst model")
        return None
    return model
```

I received the following error:

```
TypeError: blstm() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'vocab_size', 'embed_size', 'num_classes', and 'learn_rate'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your error has nothing to do with deep learning. You created a function with 5 positional arguments:

```
def blstm(inp_dim,vocab_size, embed_size, num_classes, learn_rate): 
.........
```

And you are passing one parameter:

```
....
model = blstm(inp_dim)
....
```

That's why it throws error. You should have default values for those 4 optional arguments.

In your case, it seems you have named your function mistakenly `blstm` instead of `blstm_atten`. Be careful about that

Answer (score -1):

You can find solution in error description. You call `blstm` with only one parameter but it requires 5 parameters.

```
elif m_type == "blstm":
    model = blstm(inp_dim, vocab_size, embed_size, num_classes, learn_rate)
```